# Send JSON to events in fullcalendar , what I doing wrong

Tags: jquery, json, symfony

Hi I would like to send data with events to my template, I'm using jquery fullcalendar I have controller with

```
$result = $query->getArrayResult();
$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
$json = $serializer->serialize($result, 'json');
return $this->render('SurgeryPatientBundle:VisitsCalendar:visitscalendar.html.twig',array('events'=>$json ,'content_type' => 'application/json'));
```

In my template I have

```
<meta  content="{{content_type}}" http-equiv="Content-Type" >   </meta>
events: {{events}}
```

When I executed this controller, JSON values look this (I did distance ,You will can see difrence)

> [{&quot ;id&quot ;:1,"date&quot ;:&quot ;2013-01-02T00:00:00+0100&

And error Uncaught SyntaxError:Unexpected token{ . When I change in my template to

```
events: {{events|raw}}
```

I get right data

```
[{"id":1,"date":"2013-01-02T00:00:00+01
```

But I get in my fullcalendar.min.js that kind of  error

```
Uncaugt TypeError: Cannot call method 'replate of undefinde"
```

If I set start date to 2013-01-24T15:25:00+0100 then It works

What I did wrong ? Sorry for my English

edit: It probably didn't work  because there wasn't title in the eventObject.

Answer (score 0):

That is how it works for me.

Inside Twig:

```
        {% set events %}
            {% render 'MyBundle:MyController:getEventsForCalendar' %}
        {% endset %}

        events = {{ events|raw }};

        var selector = '#calendar';
        $(selector).fullCalendar({
            ...
            events: events
        });
```

My `getEventsForCalendarAction()`:

```
public function getEventsForCalendarAction()
{
    $events = EventQuery::create()
        ->find();

    $items = array();
    /** @var $event Event */
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $item['title'] = $event->getTitle();
        $item['startY'] = $event->getStartAt('Y');
        $item['startM'] = $event->getStartAt('m') - 1;
        $item['startD'] = $event->getStartAt('d');
        $item['endY'] = $event->getEndAt('Y');
        $item['endM'] = $event->getEndAt('m') - 1;
        $item['endD'] = $event->getEndAt('d');
        $item['url'] = $this->get('router')->generate('event_page', array('id' => $event->getId()));

        $items[] = $item;
    }

    return $this->render('MyBundle:MyController:myTemplate.html.twig', array(
        'items' => $items
    ));
}
```

My `myTemplate.html.twig`:

```
[
{% for item in items %}
    {
        title: '{{ item.title }}',
        start: new Date({{ item.startY }}, {{ item.startM }}, {{ item.startD }}),
        end: new Date({{ item.endY }}, {{ item.endM }}, {{ item.endD }}),
        url: '{{ item.url }}'
    }{% if loop.last %}{% else %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
]
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `events: {{events|raw}}`, try `events: {{events|safe}}`. This worked for me.